# How can I install Touchwiz apps on Cyanogenmod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, samsung-touchwiz, system-apps, samsung-apps

I would like to know how to install Touchwiz apps on Cyanogenmod 12.X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an answer to your question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/25310/91828). Posted as an answer because I can't comment yet.

In short, you can't. The Samsung Apps need the Touchwiz framework to work. However, you can find alternatives to the apps [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2128702).